# Client processing vs Server processing

Tags: java, angularjs, mongodb, jax-rs

I am working on a project in which we are using MongoDB, java, and angularJS. I am facing a situation where I have to show thousands of records in table view 100 at a time. I have two options:

1. I should call a webservice on every click of pagination, that returns 100 records based on pagination.
2. I will bring all records at once and apply filters in angular to show 100 on a page.

Which approach is better as far as performance?

Comment: This question can't really be answered in the absence of a more precise definition of "performance".

Answer (score 1):

You never know about a client machine so you cannot determine how much or how faster a client can process records. So keeping the load on client minimal makes more sense to me by providing server side pagination.

You have more control on memory/cpu on the server side, so you can always do better processing on the servers.

If you can strike a balance on the processing load that you can put on client and on servers then you can achieve the best results.

Comment: Yes I got your point, but if we decide to go for server processing it will increase network traffic by calling number of http request. Will it affect application performance?

Comment: @SumitD There will be some overhead of multiple requests but in any case what matters is the actual data payload. Adding to my answer, you need to strike a balance with different environmental parameters client load, server load, network traffic etc.

Answer (score -1):

To fetch all records for later usage you make unlimited query which is rather slow than limited portions. At same time you try to put all amount of records at client-side memory which can lead to unnecessary performance issues if that heap is really huge. At other-side if filter parameters or even major selection is covered by indexes - you should never be thought about whole result fetch at once. MongoDB query execution is pretty fast and should not be considered as bottleneck of application. Your case depends of total records weight as for angular and possibility to build right query.